# How to generate fluid particles in geometry bulk

Tags: fluid-simulation

While simulating

a freely falling, vertical, right cylindrical block of liquid water

I found that the particle system generated by Mantaflow only traces the outer surface of the cylinder mesh, even at higher resolution of fluid sim. Subdividing the cylinders bulk didn't help either.

This can lead to aphysical behaviour like this:
[image: fig1]
*fig 1:* *upon hitting the floor, fluid volume has a hat like shape instead of a solid cylinder*

How to generate fluid particles in geometry bulk?

**Env:**
Blender v2.82a

Comment: That is how the fluid sim will look like when you haven't baked it into a mesh yet. Fluid is being emitted from the entire volume, but Blender is just showing you the surface of the liquid volume. Look at https://youtu.be/YdUWqkqcxzw?t=491 for example.

Comment: the mesh is roughly a convex hull of the particles right? so if the fluid mesh is being calculated as if there was no liquid in the bulk how does that represent the actual behaviour of a solid block of liquid?

Comment: Explaining how the mantaflow fluid sim works is a bit beyond me...but since Blender is open source, feel free to take a look at the source code. Or just bake the mesh and you'll start to see the actual results of the fluid sim.

Comment: yeah..my concern was whether the physics would differ if there were particles in the bulk too.